# Visual Studio Database project creating items that already exist

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, database-project

Curious issue with a VS 2013 database project. If I do a schema compare with my database on the left and the current TFS files on the right, it tells me I'm missing this Stored Procedure:

[image]

Solution Explorer, however, insists it's already there:

[image]

Which it is. The SQL file is on the disk and the contents are identical to the current contents of the stored procedure.

If I check the box, update and do another compare nothing happens. The sql file doesn't get checked out and schema compare still insists I need to add it.

It's not a big deal, but it is enormously irritating. Any ideas how it might be fixed?

Comment: Weird. Does the version on disk also have the `dbo.` prefix? (Probably, since you said it's identical, but just want to confirm.)

Comment: @Keith Yes, it does. Worth pointing out that in the file comparison window, VS shows nothing at all for the existing file - just empty space. It's convinced it doesn't exist at all.